# Does my app collect "Personal info" for the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, progressive-web-apps, store

I'm uploading my PWA app to the Google Play store but I'm not sure how to answer one of their questions before I submit it.  Specifically I need to indicate whether or not my app collects "Personal Info", such as name, address, phone number, etc.

The reason I'm not sure how to answer that is because I don't ask for any of that information from my users, but my users can enter in that information regarding their own customers, if they so choose.  So does that count?  Should I indicate that my app collects personal info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's agenda for this question is referring to the case if you're explicitly asking users to enter some personal data like address, location etc. and then you're using it for your business requirements.